# Failed to render a Shiny app into HTML static file using the shinylive package

Tags: r, shiny, r-shinylive

I was able to successfully render the simplest `hello` shiny app successfully, it worked fine and fast!

```
# Copy "Hello World" from `{shiny}`
system.file("examples", "01_hello", package="shiny") |>
    fs::dir_copy("myapp", overwrite = TRUE)
# Turn it into a Shinylive app
shinylive::export("myapp", "site")
# Run it
httpuv::runStaticServer("site/")
```

But I can't finish my own app, I know that `shinylive` is still experimental, but I don't know what the problem is, promptly after I search the whole repo.

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/toxintoxin/shiomix)

It fails with the following js console output:

```
load-shinylive-sw.js:37 Service Worker registered
shinylive.js:21554 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
:7446/favicon.ico:1 
        
        
        Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
shinylive.js:31930  WebR is using `PostMessage` communication channel, nested R REPLs are not available.
Xs @ shinylive.js:31930
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21) -- "Already Tomorrow"
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Platform: wasm32-unknown-emscripten (32-bit)
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Type 'contributors()' for more information and
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Type 'q()' to quit R.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: Rcpp
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: R6
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: fastmap
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: rlang
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: later
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: magrittr
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: promises
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: httpuv
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: mime
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: jsonlite
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: xtable
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: base64enc
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: digest
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: ellipsis
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: htmltools
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: fontawesome
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: sourcetools
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: crayon
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: withr
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: commonmark
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: glue
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: cachem
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: jquerylib
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: cli
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: lifecycle
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: memoise
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: fs
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: rappdirs
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: sass
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: bslib
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: codetools
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: renv
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938  preload error:Downloading webR package: shiny
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34794  Robj construction for this JS object is not yet supported
runApp2 @ shinylive.js:34794
```

Could this be related to the version of R and the system, my version of R is 4.3.2 and the OS is win11.

Any advice would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you share a link to the repo? This is a good question but not fully reproducible given the other files needed. Thanks!